# Getting niimaqdx.dll after launching application developed in labview

Tags: labview

We have developed an application using LabVIEW 2018 32 bit, and generated a build and installer. When client installed that software and launch the application with out restarting the system, they get error as below.

[image]

After restarting the system it works well.

How do we address this issue?
Can we load the required DLL after installation without restarting the System.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, driver installation requires a reboot on Windows. I don’t think there’s a workaround. Posting as comment instead of answer because I’m not completely certain that’s the case. But I think it’s needed.